# FK constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - how to figure out the issue and fix it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have issues solving the following error in EF Core.

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_EventParticipant_Events_EventId` on table `EventParticipant` may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index.

Here are my models:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 15)]
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public string OrganiserId { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(OrganiserId))]
    public IdentityUser Organiser { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeId))]
    public Models.Type Type { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<EventParticipant> EventsParticipants = new List<EventParticipant>();
}

public class Type
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
}

public class EventParticipant
{
    public string HelperId { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey(nameof(HelperId))]
    public IdentityUser Helper { get; set; } = null!;

    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(EventId))]
    public Event Event { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

If I understand correctly, the main issue here (with this exception in general) is what happens if we delete, for example, an event in the context of my data models. Do all of the event participant entries with that event id in the database get deleted as well? Doesn't the same apply if we delete an IdentityUser from the database? Do we accordingly delete the records from the EventParticipant table?

I can't exactly figure out what's the problem if we delete an event. If we have a record in the table EventParticipant with the deleted event Id, won't the EventId column actually hold the id of the deleted event and won't we have a reference to the deleted event in the `Event` property?

What am I supposed to configure for everything to work correctly?

P.P. This seems to work in the OnModelCreating override method, but I am not really sure what's happening.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EventParticipant>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Event)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127351/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: @Progman, thank you for your comment. I checked out that question before posting, but it didn't really help me to figure out how to solve it in my context.

Comment: Is this your whole model? Please also show your `modelBuilder` code.

Comment: You can't delete it because EventParticipant is dependent on EventID.  If you delete the Event, how is EventParticipant supposed to hold a reference to the Event that no longer exists? You have 2 choices like it sais. 1, change your constraint on EventID or 2 on Delete use No Action like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306882/specify-on-delete-no-action-or-on-update-no-action-or-modify-other-foreign-key

Comment: @Train, thank you for the response. I don't get how to set up no action on delete though.

Comment: @Train, like what do I put in the .HasOne() method?

Comment: In your Context class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)` is essentially removing the cascade requirement, which is why it works. Doesn't explain why there was an issue in the first place, your existing model does not have multiple cascade paths